# Python: Obtaining index of an element within a value list of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with **key:value list** pairings, and I intend to find the index of the value list that contains the desired element.

E.g., if the dictionary is:

```
my_dict = {"key1":['v1'], "key2":None, "key3":['v2','v3'], "key4":['v4','v5','v6']}
```

Then, given element `'v2'` I should be able to get index 2.

For a value list with one element, the index can be obtained with: `list(my_dict.values()).index(['v1'])` , however this approach does not work with lists containing multiple elements.

Using for loop, it can be obtained via:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
  if value is None:
    continue
  if 'v2' in value:
    print (list(my_dict.keys()).index(key))
```

Is there a neater (pythonic) way to obtain the same?

Comment: Try: `for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items()):`, but using indices with a dictionary is ... so strange.

Comment: Dictionary are not ordered so the index may change!

Comment: Consider using an `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Since Python 3.7 they are ordered

Comment: @VPfB Yes the insertion order is guaranteed to be preserved but `{'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'b': 2, 'a': 1}` evaluates to `True` so 2 dictionaries that evaluate equal can return different indices: a recipe for headaches IMO.

Comment: More than the index, I am interested in finding the key of that value. And since key:value pair share the same index,  the key can be obtained via index this way (see example of 'v1' given above). But yes, if one is using a for loop to iterate through the dictionary, then the key can be obtained directly.

Comment: @SaadH: Yeah, so you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). Finding the index just to find the key is a backwards solution (and slower than literally any reasonable solution that gets the key directly, because you do the same work for the index as for the key, then still need another linear scan of the keys to get the key from the index). I've written an answer that provides multiple ways of getting the key associated with a value without bothering to compute an index (with at least one demonstration that gets both index and key if that's truly needed).

Comment: @VPfB: And while it's only a language guarantee as of 3.7, they're ordered as an implementation detail (with some language guarantees effectively requiring them to be ordered so long as keys are never deleted) as of CPython (the reference interpreter) 3.6 (and PyPy introduced the idea and has supported it for quite a while longer, back to their 3.5 or 3.4 compatible releases IIRC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). You want to know the key that points to a value, and you think you need to find the enumeration index iterating the values so you can then use it to find the key by iteration as well. You don't need all that. Just find the key directly:

```python
my_dict = {"key1":['v1'], "key2":None, "key3":['v2','v3'], "key4":['v4','v5','v6']}

value = 'v2'
# Iterate key/vals pairs in genexpr; if the vals contains value, yield the key,
# next stops immediately for the first key yielded so you don't iterate the whole dict
# when the value is found on an early key
key_for_value = next(key for key, vals in my_dict.items() if vals and value in vals)
print(key_for_value)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEX3OcXgJgpS0NguBK/QCxQJUiMNrYloGhpKz55Okko3M/z3/3xmceamFfN@dnyUVwMdvLO7cFXWXqitaF9CkHXWnrUSSbDo1bSklu2BJrImsGMYJ9p/CLHD4ymwMqQJpvikV75DJV4mRwgIAXcJ6GwgFfx@OUgj5i0vQE7JGtQI6RpDgRRkWaWKLf/qwvsv)

That'll raise `StopIteration` if the value doesn't exist, otherwise it directly retrieves the first key where the values `list` for that key contains the desired value.

If you don't really have an XY problem, and the index is important (it shouldn't be, that's a misuse of `dict`s) it's trivial to produce it as well, changing the extraction of the key to get both, e.g.:

```python
index, key_for_value = next((i, key) for i, (key, vals) in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if vals and value in vals)
```

Mind you, this is a terrible solution if you need to perform these lookups a lot and `my_dict` isn't trivially small; it's `O(n)` on the total number of values, so a large `dict` would take quite a while to check (relative to the cost of just looking up an arbitrary key, which is average-case `O(1)`). In that case, ideally, if `my_dict` doesn't change much/at all, you'd construct a reversed dictionary up-front to find the key(s) associated with a value, e.g.:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {"key1":['v1'], "key2":None, "key3":['v2','v3'], "key4":['v4','v5','v6']}

reversed_my_dict = defaultdict(set)
for key, vals in my_dict:
    for val in vals:
        reversed_my_dict[val].add(key)
reversed_my_dict = dict(reversed_my_dict)  # Optional: Prevents future autovivification of keys
                                           # by converting back to plain dict
```

after which you can cheaply determine the key(s) associated with a given value with:

```python
reversed_my_dict.get(value, ()) # Using .get prevents autovivification of keys even if still a defaultdict
```

which returns the `set` of all keys that map to that value, if any, or the empty `tuple` if not (if you convert back to `dict` above, `reversed_my_dict[value]` would also work if you'd prefer to get a `KeyError` when the value is missing entirely; leaving it a `defaultdict(set)` would silently construct a new empty `set`, map it to the key and return it, which is fine if this happens rarely, but a problem if you test thousands of unmapped values and create a corresponding thousands of empty `set`s for no benefit, consuming memory wastefully).

Which you choose depends on how big `my_dict` is (for small `my_dict`, `O(n)` work doesn't really matter that much), how many times you need to search it (fewer searches mean less gain from reversed `dict`), and whether it's regularly modified. For that last point, if it's never modified, or rarely modified between lookups, rebuilding the reversed `dict` from scratch after each modification might be worth it for simplicity (assuming you perform many lookups per rebuild); if it's frequently modified, the reversed `dict` might still be worth it, you'd just have to update both the forward and reversed `dict`s rather than just one, e.g., expanding:

```python
# New key
my_dict[newkey] = [newval1, newval2]

# Add value
my_dict[existingkey].append(newval)

# Delete value
my_dict[existingkey].remove(badval)

# Delete key
del my_dict[existingkey]
```

to:

```python
# New key
newvals = my_dict[newkey] = [newval1, newval2]
for newval in newvals:
    reversed_my_dict[newval].add(newkey)  # reversed_my_dict.setdefault(newval, set()).add(newkey) if not defaultdict(set) anymore

# Add value
my_dict[existingkey].append(newval)
reversed_my_dict[newval].add(existingkey) # reversed_my_dict.setdefault(newval, set()).add(existingkey) if not defaultdict(set) anymore

# Delete value
my_dict[existingkey].remove(badval)
if badval not in my_dict[existingkey]:  # Removed last copy; test only needed if one key can hold same value more than once
    reversed_my_dict[badval].discard(existingkey)
    # Optional delete badval from reverse mapping if last key removed:
    if not reversed_my_dict[badval]:
        del reversed_my_dict[badval]

# Delete key
# set() conversion not needed if my_dict's value lists guaranteed not to contain duplicates
for badval in set(my_dict.pop(existingkey)):
    reversed_my_dict[badval].discard(existingkey)
    # Optional delete badval from reverse mapping if last key removed:
    if not reversed_my_dict[badval]:
        del reversed_my_dict[badval]
```

respectively, roughly doubling the work incurred by modifications, in exchange for always getting `O(1)` lookups in either direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the key corresponding to a value, you can reverse the dictionary like so:

```
reverse_dict = {e: k for k, v in my_dict.items() if v for e in v}
```

Careful with duplicate values though. The last occurence will override the previous ones.

Comment: Using `collections.defaultdict(set)` and expanding to a full loop (not just a dictcomp) would allow you to handle duplicate values at least (`set` will avoid repeating a key twice if the values of that key contain duplicates; use `list` instead if you *want* repeated keys when a key maps the same value multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best solution but this works:

```
value = 'v2'
list(map(lambda x : value in x, list(map(lambda x : x[1] or [], list(my_dict.items()))))).index(True)
```

Comment: There is *no* reason to use `map`+`lambda` here when the equivalent listcomp would be substantially clearer/more readable (and shorter to boot), and no need to listify anything but the outermost `map` just to iterate them. listcomp equivalent of your code is `[vals and value in vals for k, vals in my_dict.items()].index(True)`. Even that's wasteful, since it can't short-circuit (it generates *all* the values, when it could stop as soon as it finds the match); a short-circuiting solution would be `next(i for i, (k, vals) in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if vals and value in vals)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger and further simplification is possible by replacing `.items()` with `.values()` since the key is not used.

Comment: @VPfB: True. I was thinking of suggesting getting both index and key (since OP says they really want the key), and I think I posted a halfway solution (that gets the key and index, but only produces the latter) before deciding to write a full answer. My [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163350/364696)'s sole example that gets the index (something it's almost always nonsensical to get) produces both index and key so `.items()` is the better approach.